# ReferenceError: halalMeatInstance is not defined

Tags: solidity, truffle

I was doing a test in truffle. But i encountered this error, "ReferenceError: halalMeatInstance is not defined". I am pretty new in this truffle test thingy, actually this is my first time playing around with smart contracts and truffle test realm. It will be really helpful if anyone can point me out the mistake i made and give a solution. Thank you so much! the test file code is added below.

```
const { expectedEvent, BN } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("Web3");

const HalalMeat = artifacts.require("HalalMeat");

contract("HalalMeat", (accounts) => {

    before(async () => {
        this.owner = accounts[0];

        this.MEAT_BRANDS = {
            GHagro: "Golden Harvest Agro Industries",
            Kazifood: "Kazi Food Industries",
            AGagro: "Ahsan Group Agro Foods",
            Bengalmeat: "Bengal Meat ltd",
            Sagro: "Sadek Agro ltd"
        };

        //enums
        this.ModeEnums = {
            ISSUER: { val: "ISSUER", pos: 0 },
            VERIFIER: { val: "VERIFIER", pos: 1 },
            PROVER: { val: "PROVER", pos: 2 }
        };

        this.StatusEnums = {
            //MANUFACTURED, DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL, STORED, DELIVERING_LOCAL, DELIVERED
            manufactured: { val: "IMANUFACTURED", pos: 0 },
            delivering1: { val: "DELIVERING_INTERNATIONAL", pos: 1 },
            stored: { val: "STORED", pos: 2 },
            delivering2: { val: "DELIVERING_LOCAL", pos: 3 },
            delivered: { val: "DELIVERED", pos: 4 }
        };

        this.defaultEntities = {
            farmA: { id: accounts[1], mode: this.ModeEnums.PROVER.val },
            farmB: { id: accounts[2], mode: this.ModeEnums.PROVER.val },
            inspector: { id: accounts[3], mode: this.ModeEnums.ISSUER.val },
            distributorGlobal: { id: accounts[4], mode: this.ModeEnums.VERIFIER.val },
            distributorLocal: { id: accounts[5], mode: this.ModeEnums.VERIFIER.val },
            seller: { id: accounts[6], mode: this.ModeEnums.ISSUER.val },
            customer: { id: accounts[7], mode: this.ModeEnums.PROVER.val }
        };

    this.defaultMeatBatches ={
      0: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.Bengalmeat, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmA.id },
      1: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.Sagro, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmA.id },
      2: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.Kazifood, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmA.id },
      3: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.GHagro, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmA.id },
      4: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.AGagro, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmA.id },
      5: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.Bengalmeat, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmB.id },
      6: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.Sagro, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmB.id },
      7: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.Kazifood, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmB.id },
      8: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.GHagro, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmB.id },
      9: { brand: this.MEAT_BRANDS.AGagro, farm: this.defaultEntities.farmB.id }
      

    };

    
        this.halalMeatInstance = await HalalMeat.deployed();
    this.providerOrUrl = "http://localhost:8545";




    });

    it('should add entities successfully', async () => {
    for(const entity in this.defaultEntities){
      const { id, mode } = this.defaultEntities[entity];

      const result = await halalMeatInstance.addEntity(
        id,
        mode,
        { from: this.owner}
      );

      console.log(result);
      expectedEvent(result.receipt, "AddEntity", {
        entityId: id,
        entityMode: mode
      });
      

      //assert.equal(actual, expected, errorMessage);
    }
    });
});
```

i tried truffle test. got reference error but was expecting an emit event.

Contract: HalalMeaton list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
1) should add entities successfullybin. Attempt #1
> No events were emitted

0 passing (99ms)
1 failing

1. Contract: HalalMeat
   should add entities successfully:
   ReferenceError: halalMeatInstance is not defined
   at Context. (test\halalmeat.js:74:22)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

this is the error message i got when i used truffle test

Comment: Are you sure this line is actually setting `this.halalMeatInstance` to a value? `this.halalMeatInstance = await HalalMeat.deployed();`

Comment: i was trying to find a mistake and now i just edited this part from  this.halalMeatInstance to instance = await HalalMeat.deployed(); its working fine now but getting another error saying "TypeError: expectedEvent is not a function"

Comment: Are you sure `expectedEvent` is a function?

Comment: It looks like you named it wrong: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#expect-event

Comment: yes!!! i named it wrong! It should be expectEvent instead of expectedEvent! Thank You so much form your help! Its running fine now!